# Pass data from tableView cell is tap to second tableView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to pass data from a tableView when the cell is tap to a detailTableView. I'm not getting any errors when the detail tableView is loaded. The segue is being performed, however, the tableView remains blank. My goal to add the color to the textLabel in the cell and add the zord in the detailTextLabel within the same cell. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
// My data
struct PowerRangerData {
    let name: String
    let rangerColor: String
    let zord: String
}
// Intial vc

class DisplayVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table_View: UITableView!
    
    var rangerArray = [
        PowerRangerData(name: "Jason", rangerColor: "Gold ranger", zord: "Pyramidas Zord"),
        PowerRangerData(name: "Tommy", rangerColor: "Green ranger", zord: "Dragon Zord"),
        PowerRangerData(name: "Nick", rangerColor: "Red ranger", zord: "Phoenix Zord"),
        PowerRangerData(name: "Kira", rangerColor: "Yellow ranger", zord: "Pteranodon Zord"),
        PowerRangerData(name: "Jen", rangerColor: "Pink ranger", zord: "Time flyer 5"),
        PowerRangerData(name: "Sky", rangerColor: "Blue ranger", zord: "Delta Runner 2")
    ]
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        table_View.dataSource = self
        table_View.delegate = self
    }
    
}

    

extension DisplayVC: UITableViewDelegate {
    
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            
            if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
                
                if let index_path = self.table_View.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    
                    let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailVC
                    
                    detailVC.color = rangerArray[index_path.row].rangerColor
                    
                    detailVC.zord = rangerArray[index_path.row].zord
                }
                
            }

        }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        table_View.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
        
    }
    
}

extension DisplayVC: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rangerArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = table_View.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = rangerArray[indexPath.row].name
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
// DetailVC

class DetailVC: UIViewController {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var detailTableView: UITableView!
    
    var color = ""
    var zord = ""
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        detailTableView.delegate = self
        detailTableView.dataSource = self
        
    }

}

extension DetailVC: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        detailTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

extension DetailVC: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let rangerData: [String] = [color, zord]
        return rangerData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = detailTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailId", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = color
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = zord
            
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be order here matters `performSegue` should be before `deselectRow` for `if let index_path = self.table_View.indexPathForSelectedRow {` to have a value

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self) 
    table_View.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)  
}
```

Also `prepare` should be under `extension DisplayVC {` not `extension DisplayVC: UITableViewDelegate {`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The order did matter. Thank you!!. However, the data is appearing twice in the detailVC. Two cells are being created. Any suggestion on how to prevent that?

Comment: Replace `return rangerData.count` with return `1`